# Implementing WS-ReliableMessaging in Web services (asmx) - C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx, ws-reliablemessaging

I have been reading about WS-ReliableMessaging and would like to implement this into my web service (.asmx). Could anyone tell me how to do this?

I know to implement WS-ReliableMessaging in WCF, I just need to change the config file to use ReliableSession, so would that be the case for my web service built in .asmx.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ASMX Web Services does not support WS-ReliableMessaging. You will need to use WCF.

ASMX supports only [WS-I Basic Profile 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html), a small but highly interoperable subset of the standards from the WS-* family.